# How can I work around the program failing if there is *any* stdin?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, pipe, stdin

For example, the following works fine:

```
/usr/bin/program
```

It produces some output, and gets to result.

But if I invoke it like this:

```
echo -n | /usr/bin/program
```

or this

```
echo -n | bash -c "/usr/bin/program"
```

or even this:

```
echo -n | bash -c "wc -c; /usr/bin/program"
```

It produces some lines of output, then fails. I have no access to source of the program, so I can't even look what could cause this behavior.

And when I try to invoke it from the python script, I get the same stuff:

```
echo | python -c 'from subprocess import call; call("/usr/bin/program", shell=True)'
```

(version without "echo" prepended works fine)

I don't even have the faintest idea why that could be happening. Stdin is going to be open even if I don't explicitly specify where the program should read from, so that shouldn't be the cause.

Is there any way to work around this issue?

**EDIT:**

The last four lines from `strace` output - the only ones that differ:

```
# without echo
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {0, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {0, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {0, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {0, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
...

# with echo
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {0, 0})      = 1 (in [0], left {0, 0})
write(4, "\0\0\0j\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\377\377\377\377", 20) = 20
write(3, "\0\0\0j\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\377\377\377\377", 20) = 20
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:**

```
sleep 20 | /usr/bin/program
```

Seems that `program` waits for something to happen at stdin, and exits if it encounters a newline or EOF (we can see it from `select` call in strace output - it timeouts if input comes from "real" user). So we needed a program that doesn't write anything to stdin, while still keeping it open - `sleep` does the job.

Comment: A process always has a standard input by default. The program might be getting confused by seeing an unexpected EOF on its input. What are you trying to do, anyway; why pipe nothing into a process? For what kind of software would this be useful?

Comment: Have you tried running `strace` on your program to see how it's messing with  its stdin? That may give you clues on what's going on.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - for example, that python script is doing something different, and it gets input from stdin. And I try to execute this external process from script.

Comment: @lgeorget - I'm trying right now. I'm not familiar with strace, yet, so the only useful thing I currently see is "exit_group(1)" at the end of the output.

Comment: @lgeorget - I'm not even sure it's the stdin thing. If I type something at keyboard while it executes, it works fine, and `echo -n` shouldn't provide any input anyway.

Comment: @lgeorget - Hm, seems I am wrong - running `/usr/bin/program` and pressing return kills the program.

Comment: Ok, so, it has a fairly regular behaviour then. The only problem is that it doesn't seem to be documented. Try running a interactive program like `vim` for example with a closed `stdin` and look at what happens :D

Comment: @lgeorget - The point is, program is question seems designed to be used in batch processing mode, without any interaction. Is there some way to "fake" interactive person as input?

Comment: @lgeorget - It gets even uglier - in python "call", I specify "stdin=None", and the program works (if I don't feed anything into python). If I invoke `echo | python`, it fails.

Comment: `echo | python` and setting `stdin` to "none" is not exactly the same thing. Have you tried running it with a never-ending standard input like `/dev/zero`? Does it *read* from the standard input? Apparently yes since when you press return, it stops but that could be a workaround.

Comment: @lgeorget - I tried, `</dev/zero` gives the same effect. Inspecting the diff between two `strace` dumps, I noticed that in dump without `echo|`, open/close calls on files use 3, but with `echo|` they use 0. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Maybe bash only opens stdin to process when the first return is pressed? Because *before* I press return, situation should be equal to `echo |`.

Comment: Well, no, you can't read a return from `stdin` before opening it. It's normal than in the first case, it uses 3 and the other 0. `open` uses the first free file descriptor and in the `echo` case, file descriptor 0 (`stdin`) is already closed. No problem here.

Comment: @lgeorget - I updated the question with my results from `strace`.

Comment: @lgeorget - Okay, I think I have a great joke to tell - I got the solution. `sleep <some timeout> | program` allows it to do processing. The problem seems that it *waits* for something to get available at stdin (which can be seen from `select` call in `strace` output, so I needed the program that opens stdin, but doesn't close it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Perl one-liner that will do what you want:

```
perl -e '$SIG{CHLD} = sub{exit 0}; open $fh, "|-", @ARGV or die; sleep 20 while 1;' /usr/bin/program
```

It's essentially the same as a mythical* `sleep forever | /usr/bin/program`, except it also watches for the program to finish, and will quit immediately when it does.  If /usr/bin/program needs any args, you can tack them onto the end of the line.

*`sleep forever` doesn't work, but GNU sleep will sleep forever if you `sleep inf`!

Comment: Awesome! I was thinking about writing something like that in C, but this is so much better :)